# c# WinForms opening the Colour Dialog in child form

Tags: c#, winforms, colordialog

Hi I try to open Color Dialog from my child form (the form opened by my main form).

```
    private void terminalScreenPanel_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            TextColourDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

My user control is loosing the focus, but dialog does not open. It opens when I press the Alt key. I use ColorDialogs in the pareny form without any issues.

Comment: What's the purpose of this line of code? `MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;` while `e` is declared as `MouseEventArgs e`?

Comment: Anyway, the code doesn't help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is to show how I open the dialog. There is nothing else.

Comment: It should work. Maybe it is open but hidden behind the child form? (If both are centered..)

Comment: @TaW It should but it does not. The dialog is not hidden behind the form. Only left Alt triggers it. Other keys do not as well. Very strange. Isn't it like with the form timers?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by timers. Nor how Alt could do anything. Any KeyPress/Preview events??

Comment: I do not know as well. Did not sch a problem. it is enough form and the dialog to overlap by 1 pixel and it does not open until I press alt.

Comment: Use *TextColourDialog.ShowDialog(this);* instead.

Comment: I have tried all of the obvious variants. Same effect. Only right alt triggers the display. I just think if the dialog does not belong tho parent form.

Comment: @Taw The form timers do not trigger on the child forms. It looks same here. I do not remember the correct c# nomenclarure but tey belong to the parent form UI thread. Maybe the same is with this dialog.

Comment: What do you mean with *My user control is loosing the focus,*? BTW i tried your code with a child form and a panel and works fine.

Comment: On my form there is a user control which is loosing the focus so somewhere there is a new control which got the focus. it is a bit more complicated case.

Comment: Oh ok. Basically you are doing *complicated* things behind the scene and you think that we can help you by saying why *TextColourDialog.ShowDialog();* doesn't work? This is not a way that a question is being asked. I vote to close it.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε they are simple.

Comment: You **need** to provide code that **reproduces** the problem. Otherwise the discussion is mute.

Comment: __Moot__ it is..